# Conditional subsetting between dates in R

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I am matching precipitation isotope values to the date of precipitation events. Sample collection occurred on a 7-10 day basis, and I want to find how many samples capture a single day of precipitation. **I aim to create a new data frame with a date, precipitation amount, and isotope value.**
Here are some example data. The data frame demonstrates the structure of what I have scraped together from several repositories.

```
# example dates over three week period
start <- as.Date('2017/01/01')
len <- 21
dates <- seq(start, by = "day", length.out = len)

# example precip events in total mm accumulation 
prcp <- c(0, 1.0, 2.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0,  # week 1
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.75, 2.0,   # week 2
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)        # week 3

# sample measurements (numeric)
samp <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, -15.0, NA, NA,
          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -12.0, NA,
          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -20, NA) 

# df showing dates, the recorded precip, and the sample measurements
# notice that sample values are associated with collection date
raw <- data.frame(dates, prcp, samp)
```

In this example, there are three sample measurements.

1. The first one (-15) corresponds with three days of precipitation during the first week, which should be discarded.
2. The second sample value (-12) corresponds to a single recorded day of precipitation, which should be kept. The sample was collected on 2017-01-13, and rain fell into the collector on 2017-01-13. Sample collection was typically in the late afternoon, so I assume they capture same-day precipitation.
3. The third sample (-20) corresponds to precipitation that occurred on 2017-01-14. It was collected on 2017-01-20, and there were no other rain events between 2017-01-13 (sample #2) and 2017-01-20 (sample #3). It should also be kept.

The new data frame I am working to generate would look like the below example.

```
# dates when a single precip day occurs between sample collection dates
dates_out <- c('2017-01-13', '2017-01-14')

# example precip events in total mm accumulation 
prcp_out <- c(1.75, 2.0)

# sample measurements (numeric)
samp_out <- c( -12.0, -20) 

# df showing dates, the recorded precip, and the sample measurements
final <- data.frame(dates_out, prcp_out, samp_out)
```

Thank you for any help on my approach or alternative methods and suggestions!

Comment: *"I want to find how many samples capture a single day of precipitation"* To clarify: You are after samples that capture a single day of precipitation **in any one week**?

Comment: Hello, that is close to my intent. The goal is to match single days of precipitation occurring between sample collection dates to the sample collected after the storm. When samples collected only contain one day's rain, I can use them. If there are multiple days of rain in the sample bucket, they are less useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

key = c(rep(0,nrow(raw)))
period = c(rep(0,nrow(raw)))
i=2


for(i in 1:(nrow(raw)-1)){
  if(!is.na(raw$samp[i])){key[i+1]  = key[i]+1   ### label each sample event 
  }else{key[i+1]= key[i]}                        ### numbering after the sample 
  ### to group cumulatively into the sample. 
}

raw2 = raw %>%  mutate(key = key) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(count = sum(prcp>0)) %>% ungroup  ### count precip events per sample 

Clean = raw2 %>%  filter(count<2) %>% group_by(key) %>%      # filter samples with more than 2 precip events  
  summarize(dates = dates[which.max(prcp)], prcp = max(prcp), samp = samp[!is.na(samp)]) #gather data to one row date by precip event
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood you correctly (see my comment), here is an option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
raw %>%
    mutate(week = week(dates)) %>%
    group_by(week) %>%
    filter(sum(prcp > 0) == 1) %>%
    fill(samp, .direction = "downup") %>%
    slice_max(prcp) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 1 x 4
#  dates       prcp  samp  week
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2017-01-09  1.75   -12     2
```

Explanation: Determine the week for each `dates`; group by week and keep only those weeks where there is exactly one day of precipitation. Replace all `NA`s in `samp` with the entry when precipitation was collected. Keep the (single) row per week that  has a non-zero precipitation; then ungroup.

If you don't need the sample ID you can skip the `fill` step. If you don't want to `week` column, remove with `select(-week)` at the end.

Comment: Great! This answer gets me very close. The shortfall here is that precipitation events and sample collection events are grouped into weeks. Rain events occurring after sample collection in the same week become associated. When I do this manually, I look between collection dates for rainfall events. If there is only one, I associate it with the sample collected after rainfall.